# in an array(int) of x elements what is the last index of the array(static) ? a) x-1 b)programmer defined?

Tags: c

lets say i have an array int a[20]
and i take only 10 elements as input (and not initialised) ..so when we refer to elements shouldnt it be just 10? are those empty also counted as elements?

eg :
    in the above array the total elements are just 10 ,but the last index is 19

is this correct?

edit:
        Yes this was a qutestion in one of my tests  the sameple would be something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int a[100],i;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
     }
     //will the value of a[99] also come under "elements"?
}
```

Comment: When you do `int a[20]` then there's already 20 elements, regardless of whether you initialize them or not. The ones you don't initialize will just have rubbish values.

Comment: @Blaze with an initializer, i.e. `int a[20] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`, the remaining 10 values are zero-initialized, that is, initialized as if `a[]` had static storage duration.

Comment: This sounds like a quizz or exam question. Best if you look it up, then you learn more than from us giving you answer c)

Comment: "i take only 10 elements as input (and not initialised)"  What does this even mean? Please post some example code in either C or C++.

Comment: `int a[20]` has 20 elements. period. If you want to keep track of what elements hold meaningful values, thats your buisness ;)

Comment: what language is this question about? C and C++ are not the same. Even for something seemingly basic as arrays C and C++ are different (eg C has VLAs C++ not)

Comment: @DavidBowling That's right. On a related note, I used to think that ` int a[20] = {0}` stands for "init the whole thing with zeros"... not knowing that the first int is set to `0` for different reasons than the other 19. Luckily the result is the same. :)

Comment: @Blaze: These days in C++ you can use `int a[20]  = {};`

Comment: @Bathsheba I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: thank you everyone for clarifying my doubt , guess i was confused with the terminology of "elements"

Answer (score 3):

You should keep a count of how many elements have a valid value ... and do not attempt to read the unitialized ones.

```
int a[7];
int n = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", a+0, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5);
if (n >= 1) {
    printf("last one: %d\n", a[n - 1]);
    //printf("UB: %d\n", a[n]);
    //printf("UB: %d\n", a[6]); //a[6] is uninitialized / not assigned a value
}
```

Comment: Curious code sample used 6 `%d` rather than 7 and `a+6`.

Comment: @chux: I wanted to make sure I had a final valid (but uninitialised) array element.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `a` has 100 elements.  You then enter a value into the first 10 of those elements.

So you have an array with 100 elements, and of those the first 10 have defined values (e.g. the ones you assigned) and the rest have **indeterminate values**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually answer the question in your question....

> lets say i have an array int a[20] .....
>
> eg : in the above array the total elements are just 10 ,but **the last index is 19**

That's it! For an array of x elements the last index is a) x-1

If you have an array of 100 elements the last index is always 99 (i.e. 100-1).

It does **not** matter that you only write to 10 of the 100 elements. It just means that you have an array with 10 initialized elements and 90 uninitialized elements. But there are still 100 elements and memory have been allocated for 100 elements and the last valid index is always 99.

So you could do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int a[100],i;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);  // you should check return value here...            
  }
  a[99] = 42;  // Write to element number 100 using index 99
}
```